# How to convert exe back to Python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

Recently I converted a .py file to a .exe file.

I lost the original .py file and I'm left with the exe file.
I converted it with pyinstaller.

Is there anyway to reverse this to get my original .py file back?

Answer (score 7):

1. Use `pyinstxtractor.py`:

   ```
        python pyinstxtractor.py yourFileName.exe
   ```

   This will extract `.exe` and create a folder named `yourFileName.exe_extracted`.
2. Inside the `yourFileName.exe_extracted` folder, find the file without any extension.
3. Edit it with HxD editor and from any `__pycache__` file created with the same version of Python, copy the first row and insert it into your file.
4. Save and Rename the file with `.pyc` extension.
5. Decompile the compiled bytecode (`.pyc`) to `.py` using any online tool, like https://www.toolnb.com/tools-lang-en/pyc.html

Answer (score 2):

You could try this [python-exe-unpacker](https://github.com/countercept/python-exe-unpacker) from In Ming Loh. Not guaranteed to work though.

Comment: How does it work? I came as far as `pyinstxtractor.py help.exe` and the result was `You can now use a python decompiler on the pyc files within the extracted directory` so what do I have to do now?

Comment: Use a python decompiler on the`pyc`file.

Comment: @hjpotter92 there are 204 pyc files

Comment: Yes Thanks for the info but still, there are 204 .pyc files. Do I just go over them 1 by 1?? @hjpotter92

Comment: @S.Known Did you bother clicking on any of provided alternatives for decompiling? Did you read its documentation? Did you search for "decompiling a directory of pyc files"? Have you heard of using `*` as wildcard?

Comment: @hjpotter92 I have searched for alternatives for decompiling but I think decompyle6 is the way to go. But now I dont need to decompyle all 204 files because the most of them are actualy the libraries I used with their components. I just need to decompyle the file I made, but I dont know wich one it is from the 204.

Comment: @S.Known, we don't know either, but if you can exclude the libraries like you said, there should be a limited number left, which you can decompile in one batch. Then search for your file...

Comment: @ｒｉｃｋｅｒｔ I have made a little code in powershell that uncompyled everything and put everything into a folder I made. After that I searched trough all the .py files with notepad++ a couple times for a line of my code. But no luck. Couldnt find it. Is there a other way?