# How to recover a .py file from PyInstaller .exe?

Tags: python, system, pyinstaller, recovery, disaster-recovery

I lost my original python code that I've been working on for months, it's packed into an `.exe` using **PyInstaller** and that's all I have.

I tried this: [Exe to python with pyinstaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36581073/exe-to-python-with-pyinstaller)

I was able to extract a file that has some of my source code in it but it's filled with all this gibberish:

Graphing...

> z Value="é   z0" MÚ0c             C   s   g | ]}|  d
>   d¡qS )ú"Ú )Ú replace)Ú.0Ús© r   úGraphLEDView_1.1.pyú
>   (   s    r   c              C   s   g | ]}t  d
>   d|¡qS )z[^0-9]r   )ÚreÚsub)r   Ú LedDatar   r   r
>   r   )   s    )Údtype)é    g      @)Ú figsizei¸   é   z    Sensor
>   {}g      ü?)ÚlabelÚ   linewidthÚLEDsÚ BrightnessÚlogz

What was extracted was a file with the name of my code without the `.py` extension and a folder of `.pyc` files none of which are my code, just the dependent libraries. Can someone help me get my code back? A lot of work down the drain if I can't get it back... I feel really dumb. Thanks

Comment: Looks like maybe another viable tool at https://github.com/countercept/python-exe-unpacker

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it by going: python python_exe_unpack.py -i myprogram.exe, and I got an error, TypeError: extractFiles() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't personally used this program, you might try reaching out to the developer. Sorry I can't be of more help!

Comment: Do you use ``onefile`` or ``onedir`` for packaging? (It looks like ``onefile``)
can you provide the complete file for download?

Comment: and provide your python version: for example, Python 3.7.7(``python --version``) and packages information (``pip freeze``)

Comment: I put in a pull request to fix the error you have here: https://github.com/countercept/python-exe-unpacker/pull/16  - The version with the fix is forked here:  https://github.com/johnashu/python-exe-unpacker

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible. Pyinstaller converts the .py file into binary which your computer can understand. From what I can see, there isn't a way to convert the .exe to a .py file again.

Comment: What you say is incorrect. **It is possible** to convert .exe to .py. Here - [Converting .exe to .py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227091/how-to-convert-exe-back-to-python-script)

Answer (score 0):

Try using pyinstaller extractor: [github link](https://github.com/extremecoders-re/pyinstxtractor). It converts exe to py with the following command:

```
python pyinstxtractor.py <filename>
```

After you extract the pyc files, you can use a decompiler like [python-uncompyle6](https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6/) to get the py files. It is not guaranteed that you will get the original code, and there will be no comments, but it is the best option.