# How I can get .py from .exe compiled by auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, exe

I've compiled my python program by auto-py-to-exe, but then lost my .py file, so now I have only my .exe file. Is it possible to decompile it back to .py?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert exe back to Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227091/how-to-convert-exe-back-to-python-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following project, it seems to be what you are looking for

https://github.com/NVISOsecurity/decompile-py2exe

Also, this post is worth mentioning

[How to convert exe back to Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227091/how-to-convert-exe-back-to-python-script)