# Can I compile a python script to an executable file, so that cannot be reversed back to the source code?

Tags: python, compilation, exe, reverse-engineering

I want to create a python .exe file in order to sell it to a client, however I'm worried that python can easily be reversed and the source code can be found, rendering my work less valuable for the future. Is there any way I can compile python code and make it irreversible?

Any other suggestions to go about solving this issue are welcomed.

Comment: Check out Nuitka: https://nuitka.net/.

Answer (score 0):

you can also install auto_py_to_exe with pip, call it in your terminal to open it, just select your .py file and itll convert it to an .exe for you

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70715083/11659881) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51227091/11659881) suggest that the compilation process that you propose may be reversible.

Comment: Yeah but as far as I understand when an .exe file is produced this way it can be reversed back to its source code